# PHP is variable not working as expected

Tags: php

I have a php variable `$username` and following script:

```
<?php
echo '<a href="#">'.$username.'</a>';
?>
```

If $username contains `something <b` it bolds text. How can I prevent that?

Comment: `echo '<a href="#">'.strip_tags($username).'</a>';`

Comment: Where is the variable being set? Is it being set to a value retrieved from a database? If so, the value should have been sanitised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use htmlspecialchars

```
echo '<a href="#">'.htmlspecialchars($username).'</a>';
```

See documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: I need to wait few minutes and only then I can mark your answer as working.

Comment: @ArnasA. Never share links to your localized php documentations. English is common language here.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<a href="#">'.htmlentities($username).'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

like that:

```
<?php
echo '<a href="#">'.htmlspecialchars($username).'</a>';
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 0):

the `echo` in PHP returns the HTML of whatever you tell it should. So if you use e.g.

```
echo "This is my text which should be displayed as it is <b>";
```

the browser will translate it into the according HTML Text (every browser has built in mechanics to "repair" malformed HTML), which will be

```
<b>This is my text which should be displayed as it is</b>
```

This is not only wrong, but also a security risk. Imagine someone uses an extremely long name which would translate into javascript once the browser renders it. Your server would turn into a spambot machine.

To prevent this from happening, you have to use the according php function, which is `htmlspecialchars()` (or `htmlentities()`;

So your code will be:

```
echo '<a href="#">'.htmlspecialchars($username).'</a>'
```

and it will display the name as intended.

Comment: Actually the first code won't be translated into the second. But following text will be affected by <b> and be parsed in strong case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip (remove) HTML tags from the string.

```
echo '<a href="#">' . strip_tags($username) . '</a>';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php